# Can anybody explain what is the best way to update latest post automatically in the page?

Tags: php, javascript

Can anybody explain what is the best way to update latest post automatically in the page ?

```
(Newly added posts will just prepend to the old wall posts)
```

And

```
 (The number which tells number of newly added posts. 
Number should be displayed in the top of the wall.)
```

Like `twitter` and `facebook`, they update wall in each interval  .

What is the technique they use ?

(I know i can set up the timeInterval in JS. But I need to send a request to server only if any new post added to the system.)

```
(Using cron or something we can just go and hit the client ?.
 In phone there is a method called "PUSH". )
```

Comment: "But I need to send a request to server only if any new post added to the system." You don't know if there's a new post to show unless you ask the system. Use an interval and ask it.

Comment: did u look itno `AJAX` ?

Comment: Kind of , some cron will be running in the system to check the latest updates , if yes some request to browser (client) telling browser to Make an ajax call to server (Instead of many ajax call using setInterval)

Answer (score 0):

You can set cron job on server.. it will run page on specified time interval.

you can find it on this url :

http://docs.phplist.com/CronJobExamples

Comment: How to update some area of the page (DIV) using server side cron.